# Apache Sqoop connectivity error

Tags: mysql, hadoop, jdbc, bigdata, sqoop

I am getting the following error while trying to list databases from mysql database using sqoop. I am using Cloudera VM CDH4 were it does not come with MySql pre installed by default. I installed MySql as per cloudera tutorial. Now I am trying to list database from MySQl and it fails. Is there any jdbc connectivity issue?

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ sqoop list-databases --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost.localdomain" --user root --password aaaaaaaa
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
14/12/17 11:52:07 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.3-cdh4.7.0
14/12/17 11:52:07 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for list-databases:
14/12/17 11:52:07 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --user
14/12/17 11:52:07 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: root
14/12/17 11:52:07 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --password
14/12/17 11:52:07 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: aaaaaaaa

Try --help for usage instructions.
usage: sqoop list-databases [GENERIC-ARGS] [TOOL-ARGS]

Common arguments:
   --connect <jdbc-uri>                         Specify JDBC connect
                                                string
   --connection-manager <class-name>            Specify connection manager
                                                class name
   --connection-param-file <properties-file>    Specify connection
                                                parameters file
   --driver <class-name>                        Manually specify JDBC
                                                driver class to use
   --hadoop-home <hdir>                         Override
                                                $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME_ARG
   --hadoop-mapred-home <dir>                   Override
                                                $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME_ARG
   --help                                       Print usage instructions
-P                                              Read password from console
   --password <password>                        Set authentication
                                                password
   --password-file <password-file>              Set authentication
                                                password file path
   --skip-dist-cache                            Skip copying jars to
                                                distributed cache
   --username <username>                        Set authentication
                                                username
   --verbose                                    Print more information
                                                while working

Generic Hadoop command-line arguments:
(must preceed any tool-specific arguments)
Generic options supported are
-conf <configuration file>     specify an application configuration file
-D <property=value>            use value for given property
-fs <local|namenode:port>      specify a namenode
-jt <local|jobtracker:port>    specify a job tracker
-files <comma separated list of files>    specify comma separated files to be copied to the map reduce cluster
-libjars <comma separated list of jars>    specify comma separated jar files to include in the classpath.
-archives <comma separated list of archives>    specify comma separated archives to be unarchived on the compute machines.

The general command line syntax is
bin/hadoop command [genericOptions] [commandOptions]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
sqoop list-databases --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost \
  --username root \
  --password aaaaaaaa
```

Problem was there is not options `--user` for Sqoop instead you have to use `--username`.